# Selenium RemoteWebDriver with Chromium Embedded

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromium-embedded

I might be misunderstanding something here so apologies if that is the case.

I'd like to connect Selenium to a pre-existing instance of Chromium Embedded both running inside the same application. I thought this would be possible using a RemoteWebDriver and setting the `remote-debugging-port` argument however I get a `OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException` with the message `Unexpected error`.

Is what I'm after possible? I need to control the Window in which Chromium is running so a standard Selenium setup is not possible.

I've taken my implementation from Example 2 in the section **Controlling ChromeDriver's lifetime** [here](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started).

Here's the complete contents of `MainWindow.xaml.cs`. Browser is the `x:Name` of the CEF control.

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

using CefSharp;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace SeleniumTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private RemoteWebDriver web_driver;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeCefWithSettings();

            InitializeComponent();

            InitializeBrowser();
        }

        private void InitializeCefWithSettings()
        {
            CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-media-stream", "1");
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu-shader-disk-cache", "1");
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("remote-debugging-port", "9515");

            CefSharpSettings.WcfEnabled = true;

            Cef.Initialize(settings);
        }

        private void InitializeBrowser()
        {
            BrowserSettings browserSettings = new BrowserSettings();
            browserSettings.FileAccessFromFileUrls = CefState.Enabled;
            browserSettings.UniversalAccessFromFileUrls = CefState.Enabled;
            browserSettings.WebSecurity = CefState.Disabled;
            Browser.BrowserSettings = browserSettings;

            var options = new ChromeOptions();

            web_driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:9515"), options.ToCapabilities());
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Last time I looked you couldn't connect to a running instance, is it now supported? You can connect `Puppeteer Sharp` to a running instance. What exactly are you trying to do with `Selenium`?